# In Vue.js, how to call a function from Google Maps click event?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Google Maps API in a Nuxt.js app in SPA mode and I want, from the gmap click event, to call a function in the Vue.js methods

I tried the usual `this.createInfoWindow()`, but `this` is not the `VueComponent`, it's the `Window`.

In my component I initialize the google maps and add the click event in the vue mounted:

```js
async mounted() {
  // Map initalization
  const google = await gmapsInit()
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('g-map'),
    this.mapOptions
  )
  // Add click event
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', e => {
    // function call not working
    this.createInfoWindow(e.latLng)
  })
}
```

And in the vue methods, I have the function:

```js
methods: {
  async createInfoWindow(latLng) {
    const google = await gmapsInit()
    const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'InfoWindow',
      position: latLng
    })
    infoWindow.open(this.map)
  }
}
```

Everything seems to be working, except the function call: `this.createInfoWindow(e.latLng)`

How can I call the function `createInfoWindow` from the click event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you stated, `this` does not refer to your Vue instance inside the click handler.  Use a closure.

```
  // Add click event
  const that = this
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', e => {
    // function call not working
    that.createInfoWindow(e.latLng)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" is not accessed within the listener function, hence the existence of "this.createInfoWindow" is not known.
A closure helps you capture and store "this" for use in the scope of the child function (the listener function in this problem), hence Steve's solution works

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33377795)